# Oracle Virtual box is not displaying ip

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am using oracle virtual box and inside that running fedora .It was showing ip earlier but now it showing below , no ip. I am running bridge mode.

[image]

Comment: 1) What is VirtualBox version and host o.s.? 2) Did you change network mode recently? 3) Can you supply a) the output of "VBoxManage list bridgedifs" , b) output of "VBoxManage showvminfo yourVmName", c) guest logfile

Comment: @gile VirtualBox is 5.0.14 and host os is Win7 . No i did not changed it recently .Where should i run these commands as on terminal this command is not working..

Comment: It should be in C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox or whatever you installed VirtualBox. Look at https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html for more informations about VBoxManage.